# Is there something different widget setting on android Q?

Tags: android, android-widget

my app widgets are not appear in widget list on android Q.
but when OS is less or equal than android P, it appear on list.

AndroidMenifest.xml :

```
<receiver android:name=".widget.Day7Widget">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/widget_day7_provider"/>
</receiver>
```

widget_day7_provider.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_day7"
    android:minWidth="368dp"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="600000"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_week"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

has anyone ever experienced the same bug as me?